# AngularJS routes can't be recognized on manual refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Hi I followed a tutorial: http://omarriott.com/aux/angularjs-html5-routing-rails/

Here's my manual.js.coffee.erb

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
#= require_tree ./templates

@Bento = angular.module('bento', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'infinite-scroll'])

# Pre-cache templates
Bento.run ($window, $templateCache) ->
  templates = $window.JST

  for fileName of templates
    fileContent = templates[fileName]
    $templateCache.put(fileName, fileContent)
    # Note that we're passing the function fileContent,
    # and not the object returned by its invocation.

#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./services
#= require_tree ./directives
```

My routes.js.coffee.erb

```
@Bento.config ["$routeProvider", ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider.when("/",
    controller: "ActivitiesController"
    templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('templates/user/activities.html.haml') %>"
    redirectTo: (current, path, search) ->
      if search.goto
        "/" + search.goto
      else
        "/"
  ).when("/projects/activities",
      controller: "ProjectAllActivitiesController"
      templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('templates/projects/activities.html') %>"
      redirectTo: "/example"
  ).when("/projects/:id",
      controller: "ProjectCtrl"
      templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('templates/projects/list.html') %>"
      redirectTo: (current, path, search) ->
        if search.goto
          "/projects/:id" + search.goto
        else
          "/projects/:id"
  ).otherwise redirectTo: "/"
]
```

And lines that I added to my config/routes.rb file

```
match "api" => proc { [404, {}, ['Invalid API endpoint']] }, via: [:post]
match "api/*path" => proc { [404, {}, ['Invalid API endpoint']] }, via: [:post]

match "/*path" => redirect("/?goto=%{path}"), via: [:post]
```

Since I'm using rails 4, I need to add a `via`

**#** sign is adding whenever I refresh my root path `localhost:3000/` but it's not working in nested URLs like `localhost:3000/projects/1` it's still reading my routes for RAILS.

PS: Whenever i refresh `localhost:3000/projects/activities` for example, it's still reading my rails routes instead of going to `localhost:3000/example`.

Comment: Sorry for asking but I already solved this issue by transferring the `match` lines above my projects and activities routes. If you are using Rails 4 do not put the `match` lines of code to the bottom.